# OIDC client js creating multiple iframes for check session in React JS

Tags: reactjs, oidc-client-js

OIDC client js creating multiple iframes for check session in React JS. For every page navigation, 2 new iframes are getting added. What am I doing wrong? Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Could you add more details to help understand the problem?  
Stackoverflow won't do magic... Please provide the code where you use the OIDC lib

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/620
More details are available in this issue.